# Android chose image from gallery or camera show option together

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gallery

On my onClick method I have called two new intents one for taking pictures with camera and one for choosing image from gallery. However whenever I allow the two intents before starting the activity, the pop-up allowing dialogue always layover each other.

```
Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);

Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);
```

I will first see the option to allow choosing images from gallery and after swiping it down, then I'll see option to allow camera. How can I show it in one popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following....

```
private void showPickImageDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builderSingle.setTitle("Select One Option");

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    arrayAdapter.add("Gallery");
    arrayAdapter.add("Camera");

    builderSingle.setNegativeButton(
            "cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    builderSingle.setAdapter(
            arrayAdapter,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 1);
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);
                            break;
                    }

                }
            });
    builderSingle.show();
}
```

Hope this works for you!!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! That solved my problem, thank you

Comment: @JerryKo Happly to help! Cheers!